# GROUP BY interval overlapping timestamp MySQL query

Tags: mysql, group-by, timestamp, intervals

I've been reading other questions and had no luck. I have a table with columns (stamp,value). The 'stamp' column stores hourly timestamps. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve SUM(value) for intervals of 24 hours depending on a range of timestamps specified in the query:

```
SELECT stamp, 
       Sum(value) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  stamp >= Date_sub('2012-12-02 05:00:00', INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND stamp < '2013-01-01 05:00:00' 
GROUP  BY Date(stamp)
```

The result I'm looking for would look like this:

```
stamp                      value
2012-12-02 05:00:00        12024
2012-12-03 05:00:00        11211
2012-12-04 05:00:00        19834
...
2013-01-01 05:00:00        10232
```

Actual table looks like this:

```
stamp                      value
2012-12-01 01:00:00        345
2012-12-01 02:00:00        100
2012-12-01 03:00:00        104
2012-12-01 04:00:00        103
2012-12-01 05:00:00        101
2012-12-01 06:00:00        102
...
2013-01-01 05:00:00        207
2013-01-01 06:00:00        307
2013-01-01 07:00:00        223
...
```

***Note that the stamp column's datatype is timestamp**

Comment: So is the `stamp` returned above the earliest timestamp per date group?

Comment: Please do not select columns which are not in your `GROUP BY`. MySQL extends this functionality but it's behavior is not exact and should be avoided.

Comment: Whenever possible, use `x BETWEEN y AND z` instead of `x >= y AND x <= z`.

Comment: The stamp returned above is the most recent per date group. Ex. SUM all the values from 2012-12-01 05:00:00 to 2012-12-02 05:00:00.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post because I had a typing error concerning 'DATE(stamp)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to set the hours to 5, to be consistent with your range.  If so, you can do this:

```
SELECT cast(date(stamp) as datetime) + interval 5 hour
       Sum(value) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  stamp >= Date_sub('2012-12-02 05:00:00', INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND stamp < '2013-01-01 05:00:00' 
GROUP  BY Date(stamp)
```

But, I think you might actually want to phrase this a bit differently:

```
SELECT cast(date(stamp - interval 5 hour) as datetime) + interval 5 hour
       Sum(value) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  stamp >= Date_sub('2012-12-02 05:00:00', INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND stamp < '2013-01-01 05:00:00' 
GROUP  BY Date(stamp - interval 5 hour)
```

This actually realigns the dates on the 5-hour boundary.

Note:  these queries are untested, so may contain syntax errors.

This is assuming that the timestamp is really a datetime.  If it is a UNIX timestamp, you need to convert it first.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do get the stamps as expected but the sum(value) seems off. I checked and realized that the stamp column is a UNIX timestamp instead of datetime.