# MYSQL - datetime, group by, correct query

Tags: mysql

---

UPDATE
I found this query : 
    SELECT CONCAT(DATE(gid), ' / ', HOUR(gdate), ':00:00 to ', CONCAT(HOUR(gdate), ':59:59')) as slice,
  COUNT(*) 
FROM t_table
GROUP BY 
  DATE(gdate), 
  HOUR(gdate);

It doesnt output a ZERO when there is no data for a period of 8 hours or for a day. Is there a way ?

---

I have a table which has 3 fields :

> - gid (int)
> - gdate (datetime)
> - ginfo (text)

I want to find the correct query that would ouput the number of items (field ginfo) for every 8 hours every day between two dates. I am not sure if it's clear so I can try to schematize it :

> The first date is : 2013/10/01.
>  The second date is :
>   2013/10/03.
>  For the first day the PHP output would be for
>   example:
>  2013/10/01 00:00-07h59 : 8
>  2013/10/01 08:00-15h59 :
>   5
>  2013/10/01 16:00-23h59 : 7
>  For the second day the PHP output
>   would be for example :
>  2013/10/01 00:00-07h59 : 2
>  2013/10/01
>   08:00-15h59 : 3
>  2013/10/01 16:00-23h59 : 1
>  etc.

In the table, there are 20 items for 2013/10/01.
In the table, there are 6 items for 2013/10/02.

I can't find the correct query.
Can anyone help me ?
Excuse my poor english.

Comment: If there are no rows for the time period, should there be a row with a zero, or is no row OK?

Comment: can you give us sqlfiddle ?

Comment: It would be better to find a ZERO. It would avoid to spend some time with PHP scripts if the query is well formated :=)

Comment: sqlfiddle for the creation of the table ? The table is quite simple (only 3 fields as I described above). For the query, I found something like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708027/mysql-select-hour-in-datetime-and-group. But there is no ZERO and it is done hour by hour. I need the 8 hour interval.

Comment: See the next post. I gave you 2 sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(gid) FROM [table_name] WHERE (gdate>=2013/10/01 00:00) and (gdate<=2013/10/01 07:00)
UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(gid) FROM [table_name] WHERE (gdate>=2013/10/07 00:00) and (gdate<=2013/10/01 16:00)
UNION ALL
... bla bla with your conditions
```

i think the format date is not correct you can looking for format date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the query but it displays something like that : COUNT(gid) / 507 / 507

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(ginfo) 
FROM 'TABLE_NAME'
WHERE gdate BETWEEN 'from_date' AND 'to_date' 
GROUP BY (date(gdate) + INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is very closed to what I am looking for but there is two more small things. 1- I'd like to see the periode in the output (there is only the count). 2- Could there be a ZERO if there is no value ? (cf. Bohemian answer). Thanks

Comment: I checked well and there is a problem because I have entries from 00h00 to 23h59 for a day and in the output there is only one line for that day. The interval doesn't work ?

Comment: can you give the case in sqlfiddle ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07486/3. In this case, I don't have a ZERO when there is no data in a specific time interval

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/018ab/1. In this case, I don't have the "8 hours interval" in my output. This is grouped by days.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`gdate`)/(480 * 60)) AS timekey,count(*),`gdate`
FROM your_table
WHERE gdate BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-10-03' 
GROUP BY timekey
```

You can refer following for detailed answer

[GROUP BY interval overlapping timestamp MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487945/group-by-interval-overlapping-timestamp-mysql-query)

[Group mysql query by 15 min intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793994/group-mysql-query-by-15-min-intervals/2794021#2794021)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. The output is quite strange for me. I don't know the notion of timekey. I'll check the URLs. Actually, it does not output what I really want.